# Group_Concat function doesn't work on simba driver with Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

If my query contains Group_Concat and is send to bigquery using simba jdbc driver I get error that function Group_Concat not found.

When the same query is run from bigquery web interface it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the function using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) is [`STRING_AGG`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#string_agg). In the UI, you can enable standard SQL by unchecking "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options".

Comment: There is no over clause over String_agg while Group_concat does. I need to do a string concatenation over some partition.

Comment: If we use legacy SQL, its Rest API doesn't support named parameter.

Comment: You can use`STRING_AGG` as an aggregate function with both `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, which may let you create the kind of result that you want. An upcoming BigQuery release will support `STRING_AGG` as an analytic function